# Lazy eager loaded relationship missing in toArray()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Laravel 5.8

I am lazy loading an user with the related customer which has a one-to-one-relation with a crmaccount-object

The models are working so that when i retrieve the eager-loaded entity it shows all of the nested relationships.

One row later i use the "toArray()" method on that object and the output is missing the third-level-relations.

The only thing which maybe some kind of special regarding the "crmaccount"-model is that it holds a column which is json an has to be casted.

Any idea what is going on here?

[image]

[image]

All of these happens in a middleware. No difference if i use with or load.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $UserData = \Auth::user();
    if($UserData){
        $User = \App\Login::with(['role','customer','customer.crmaccount'])->find($UserData->id);
        dump($User);
        dd($User->toArray());


        $UserData['isAdmin'] = false;
        if($UserData['role']['name'] === 'Admin'){
            $UserData['isAdmin'] = true;
        }
        $request->request->add(['UserData' => $UserData]);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Login

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Login extends Authenticatable{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','customer_id','role_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    /* */
    public function Role(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
    public function Customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
    /**
     * [hasOpportunities Ruft alle Opportunities des Users ab. Da diese lediglich zwei Entitäten weiter sind, kann anstatt von dot-notated Lazy-Load auch die hasManyThrough-ORM-Methode genutzt werden]
     * @return [hasManyThrough-Relation] [Die hasManyThrough-ORM-Beziehung]
     */
    public function hasOpportunities(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Opportunity',
            'App\Customer',

            'id',
            'customer_id',
            'customer_id'
        );
    }
    /**
     * [hasSalesreps Ruft alle SalesReps des Users ab. Da diese lediglich zwei Entitäten weiter sind, kann anstatt von dot-notated Lazy-Load auch die hasManyThrough-ORM-Methode genutzt werden]
     * @return [hasManyThrough-Relation] [Die hasManyThrough-ORM-Beziehung]
     */
    public function hasSalesreps(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Salesrep',
            'App\Customer',

            'id',
            'customer_id',
            'customer_id'
        );
    }
}
```

Customer

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $visible = ['id','name'];

    protected $fillable = ['name'];


    public function crmaccount(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Crmaccount');
    }

    public function Salesreps()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Salesrep');
    }

    public function Prospects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Prospect');
    }

    public function Trees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Salesreptrees');
    }

    public function Opportunities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Opportunity');
    }

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Login');
    }
}
```

Crmaccount

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Crmaccount extends Model{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $visible = ['id','name','crm_system','customer_id','crm_api_config'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','crm_system','customer_id','crm_api_config'
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'crm_api_config' => 'array'
    ];
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `with(['Role','Customer', 'Customer.crmaccassasad'])`; might be an issue with omitting the intermediary relationship. Also note, relationships are `camelCase`, so `Role` should be `role`, and `Customer` should be `customer`; `crmaccassasad` is fine (but could be clearer). Also, do you need to use `->toArray()`? Does `$request->request->add()` not accept an `object`?

Comment: Thank you for that response. I messes arround with the column names resulting in "crmaccassasad" ;-)

Where exactly are those naming conventions stated? I'll update my models and report.

Comment: All throughout the documentation; `public function posts()`, `public function comments()`, etc. etc. Can be `camelCase` or `snake_case`, but avoid upper case (model names are `StudlyCase`, etc.) They're just conventions though; they don't cause an issue. So, is `crmaccassasad` a `column` or a `relationship`? It looks like it should be `crmacc` from the first image.

Comment: I changed the model-methods to lowercase and updated the screenshots - same result

Comment: Can you post your models? Might have something to do with the `visible` and/or `hidden` properties; those control which attributes are shown when the model is converted to an array/json/etc. (I see `#visible: array[2]` in your `customer` model, might be the case)

Comment: Added the modesl (yeah, i know i have to fix all of those method names :) )

Comment: I wasn't gonna say anything :P Try adding `crmaccount` to `protected $visible`; see if it is included. I'm not 100% if that property affects relationships, but I *think* it does.

Comment: You made my day :) I also had that thought but went like "ohh they would state THAT in the documentation marked red".

It works after adding the method name or "property" to the visible array of the "mother", in this case "customer".

Please post your comment again as a post, so i can upvote and mark as solution.

Comment: Perfect :) This is definitely good to know; might be a "gotcha" in the future. Glad I could help. Feel free to post a self-answer with your solution. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, saw your edit; 1 second; I'll convert to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On every model, there is a `protected $visible = [];` and `protected $hidden = []` attribute. These control the attributes that are available when the model is converted to an `object`, `array` or `json`. This includes `relationships`, as Laravel internally converts them to attributes, so omitting them from `visible`, or including them in `hidden` will cause them to not be available.

In `Customer.php`:

```
protected $visible = ['id','name'];
```

Since `crmaccount` is not in that array, only `id` and `name` will be available. Simply add `crmaccount` to the array to handle:

```
protected $visible = ['id','name', 'crmaccount'];
```

Alternatively, use `hidden` to explicitly set the attributes you don't want to show, and `relationship`, if loaded via `->with()` will show by default.